Why does my YTD calculation based on comparing time to current month not work in a DAX measure?
I have the following data structure:

A calendar table that includes the numerical column [Month] (1,2...12). The latest date in the calendar table is 20 Aug 2024 (or T-1).
A data table that includes a date column [Data_Date], with monthly data (i.e. 2024-01-01, 2024-02-01 etc.) from June 2020 up to June 2024; it also includes a [Volume] column

I am looking to create a table with two columns:

Year, where I have the [Year] column from my calendar table
Volume YTD, where I want to display the volume for the first X months of each year, with X = latest month in the latest year for which volume data is available, i.e. 6

In other words, the 2020 row should show volume for June 2020 (because there is no volume data for Jan 2020 to May 2020). The 2021 row should show volume for Jan 2021 to Jun 2021. The 2022 row should show volume for Jan 2022 to Jun 2022 etc.
I have created the following measures to calculate Volume YTD:
TxnValue:= SUM(Data[Volume])

TxnValue YTD:=CALCULATE([TxnValue],FILTER('Calendar','Calendar'[Month]<=6)) - THIS WORKS

Test: MONTH(CALCULATE(MAX(Data[Data_Date]),ALL(Data[Data_Date]))) = 6 - THIS CORRECTLY RETURNS 6

TxnValue YTD:=CALCULATE([TxnValue],FILTER('Calendar','Calendar'[Month]<=MONTH(CALCULATE(MAX(Data[Data_Date]),ALL(Data[Data_Date]))))) - THIS DOESN'T WORK

Why does the last formula not return the correct volume for the first 6 months but instead the volume for the full year?

Can you share some data and your model?
